# What is causing the conflict between these two Google Analytics tracking scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am getting a ton of self-referred traffic on my website. I believe it is due to these two tracking codes.. I am not sure that I need both, but want to be sure if I do or not.

We want sub-domain tracking to work (first script), and obviously the regular GA tracking info as well (2nd script is the out-of-the-box script).

```
`<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function()    {(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),     m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)     })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-5402569-1', 'auto',{‘allowLinker’: true });
  ga(‘require’, ‘linker’);ga(‘linker:autoLink’,     ['goaupair.com’,‘community.goaupair.com’,'knowledge.goaupair.com']);
ga(‘send’, ‘pageview’);
</script>`

`<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-5402569-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript';     ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' :     'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';var s =     document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need both (in fact you will get most likely double counting of pageviews). The first script is the current version (Universal Analytics). The second script is previous version of the GA tracking script.

You should remove the second version altogether. As far as subdomain tracking is concerned you do not need any special tracking for that - just make sure that your domain is added to the referral exclusion list in the property settings, and that the cookieDomain is set to "auto" when you create the tracker (which it is, so simply lose the the both lines for the linker).

Linking between domains is only necessary if you want to do cross domain tracking between two different domains. The point if cross domain tracking is to transfer the client id that is stored in a cookie, and since your domain and subdomain share their cookies anyway you do not need special configuration.

The only thing that's important is the "auto" setting for the cookie domain, else visitors entering via the subdomain will get a new clientid (and thus be counted as new visitors) when they enter the main domain.

Comment: Thanks. It has been a while since I dealt with these issues, working at a new job and their analytics is a mess, with tons of self-referrals, and the subdomain is the only place with both codes. The TLD has the top code above. Do you think I should remove the allowLinker descriptions? They already have the subdomain exclusion rule setup in admin.

Comment: You should remove it, and the old tracking code. Since this uses the same tracking id the account has probably double counted up to now, so expect radically different metrics (less pageviews on the subdomain to start with) after you have cleaned up the code.